# Include custom js file in with php function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a custom made function to include custom javascript files depending on de page viewed.
This is the function:

```
function custom_jsinclude($php,$jsfile) { //
$filename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if($filename === $php) {
echo "<script src=\"js/$jsfile\"></script>\n";
  } else {
    exit("Couldnt find file");
  }
}
```

Back in my php file  I include it like this(between the head tags).

```
<?php
 require_once('inc/functions.php');
 custom_jsinclude("somepage.php","custom-scrollTo.js");
?>
```

When i load up the page the javascript file is included(checking the source). But it doesnt work.

Then i tried the old fashion way:
    `<script src="js/custom-scrollTo.js"></script>`
And is works fine...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome to my homepage</title>
<script src="js/custom-scrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/somepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

What am i missing here?

The scrollTo code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#prlmenu li").click(function(){
    var indexli = $(this).index();
    var indexh3 = indexli;
    var scrollto = $('h3:eq('+indexli+')').offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrollto +'px' },"fast");


});


$("div.backtotop").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "130px" },"fast"); 
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if($("html, body").scrollTop() > 1510) {
            $("div.backtotop").fadeIn("slow");

        } else {
            $("div.backtotop").hide();  
        }
});

});
```

Comment: at a first glance you're missing an '**s**'

Comment: can you possibly provide more code?

Comment: When your checking the source from the browser, you should visit the URLs that you are generating from your PHP script, to check for broken links.

Comment: it's not broken i can visit it.

Comment: @rlemon what code you want to see?

Comment: Can you put the source code that being generated by this function? I mean the HTML code

Comment: anything more than you have here. If you can visit the location locally the include works. There must be other underlying issues like possibly where you are doing the include?

Comment: give us the scrollTo code! it is what is not working... i mean really.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/'.$jsfile.'"></script>\n';
```